# Best way to disable all buttons, until a password is put in the textbox field?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have about 30 buttons on my form and I want to disable 28 of them. The one button that works is the Save password button, and once that is clicked with the right password all the buttons are enabled. Then there's the clear button to disable it again.

I'm wondering if there's a better/efficient way to do this compared to what it looks like now.

```
Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = False
        Button3.Enabled = False
        Button4.Enabled = False
        Button5.Enabled = False
        Button6.Enabled = False
        Button7.Enabled = False
        Button8.Enabled = False
        Button9.Enabled = False
        Button10.Enabled = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub Clear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Clear.Click
        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button2.Enabled = True
        Button3.Enabled = True
        Button4.Enabled = True
        Button5.Enabled = True
        Button6.Enabled = True
        Button7.Enabled = True
        Button8.Enabled = True
        Button9.Enabled = True
        Button10.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: If they are adjacent to each other, you can place them inside a panel and disable the panel. If they are not adjacent to each other, then you can do a for each loop and enable/disable each button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to put all and only those `Buttons` on a `Panel` and disable that `Panel`, as suggested in the comments.

Another option is put those `Buttons` on a `Panel` along with other controls that are not `Buttons` and then disable all the `Buttons` like so:

```vb
Private Sub EnableButtons(enable As Boolean)
    For Each btn In myPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
        btn.Enabled = enable
    Next
End Sub
```

If you can't put those `Buttons` in a different container then you might set the `Tag` property of each one to the same value and then filter on that:

```vb
Private Sub EnableButtons(enable As Boolean)
    For Each btn In Controls.OfType(Of Button)().Where(Function(b) CStr(b.Tag) = "Some Value")
        btn.Enabled = enable
    Next
End Sub
```

However you implement that method, you can call it from the `Click` event handlers of the other two and pass either `True` or `False`, depending on whether you want to enable or disable them.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Took me awhile to understand panels, but I managed to get through it.

Answer (score -1):

To get all buttons in one control, for instance a GroupBox or your Form, use:

```
IEnumerable<Button> GetAllButtons(Control control)
{
    return control.Controls.OfType<Button>();
}
```

Comment: That code is C# and this question is tagged VB.NET. Also, it doesn't actually answer the question as asked, which was not how to get all `Buttons` in a container. I will retract my down-vote if those points are addressed, although it seems like addressing the latter would simply be a repeat of the answer I had already provided.